# Is it ok to review the code of an acquaintance?

Tags: discussion

[This post was posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/191861/32131) by an acquaintance with whom I am directly related. I'm helping her ramp up on Python. Usually, I wait for the community to answer the questions posted by her (since it gets her objective feedback from the best folks out there), but since this post didn't have any feedback for quite a few hours, I [decided to answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/191940/32131) it.

Is this ok by the community guidelines, and is there anything that I should be taking care of?

Comment: _this post didn't have any feedback for quite a few hours_ - you're very impatient ;-) give it a  couple of days.

Comment: After a while on a site you're not sure who counts as an acquaintance..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be game for you to answer her questions, at least if you don't try to game the system.

It still would be good for her experience if she would get not only answers from you but from different users as well to see a wide range of how it could/should be done better.

Comment: True that. The previous 15 posts by her all had answers from the community so I just monitor the answers she gets, but this time there were none so I thought I would step in and check here as well.